# ASP.net with C# Keeping a List on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

My situation goes like this:  I have these lists with data inserted into them when a user presses an ADD button, but I guess on postback the Lists are re-zeroed.  How do you keep them preserved? I've been looking for the answer, but I guess I don't quite understand how to use the session, etc.

I'm very new to ASP.net and not much better with C# it would seem.

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{


 List<string> code = new List<string>();


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bleh   

}

protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    code.Add(lstCode.Text);
}
```

Comment: When you say lists, do you mean `ListView` controls, or something else?

Comment: @SouthShoreAK He means the generic list: `List<T>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use this property to store information:

```
public List<string> Code
{
    get
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Session["Code"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Code"] = new List<string>();
        }
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["Code"] as List<string>;
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Code"] = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is, according to me, the best way to do this.

Comment: @JakeGaston just copy this property into your Main class. And instead of your "code" variable, use "Code" property.

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze I'm having a similar issue, can you tell me what you mean by use the Code "property?"

Comment: "Code" is just a name of the property. It could be any other name. If you want to know what property is, take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties

Answer (score 3):

This is an oddity in ASP.NET.  Whenever you programmatically add items to a collection control (listbox, combobox), you must re-populate the control on *each postback.*

This is because the Viewstate only knows about items added during the page rendering cycle.  Adding items at the client-side only works the first time, then the item is gone.

Try this:

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                 Session["MyList"] = new List<string>();
            }   
            ComboBox cbo = myComboBox; //this is the combobox in your page
            cbo.DataSource = (List<string>)Session["MyList"];
            cbo.DataBind();
        }




        protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> code = Session["MyList"];
            code.Add(lstCode.Text);
            Session["MyList"] = code;  
            myComboBox.DataSource = code;
            myComboBox.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I'll try this out.  What is the namespace (using System...) to get the session keyword to work, though?

Comment: Session is not a keyword. It's a property of type HttpSessionState. You can access it like this HttpContext.Current.Session.

Comment: is using Session correct way for this? may be user has two open tabs of the same page and wants works on two different copies of the same page...

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep values between post backs.

You can use session to preserve list:

```
// store the list in the session
List<string> code=new List<string>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(!IsPostBack)
  Session["codeList"]=code;

}
 // use the list
void fn()
{
 code=List<string>(Session["codeList"]); // downcast to List<string> 
 code.Add("some string"); // insert in the list
 Session["codeList"]=code; // save it again
}
```