# Structure not being added to Collection in VB.Net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my application, a user selects an item and quantity from a list box, and clicks the add button to add the item. When done, they can click Order to check out.

When a user clicks add, the selected item is made into a CustomerItem structure, which I try to add to a Collection (CustomerItemsList).

The problem is, the items are not showing up in the list. I cant tell if this is a scope or type issue?

My structure looks like this:

```
    Structure CustomerProduct
    Public Description As String
    Public ItemQty As Integer
    Public BulkFee As Double
    Public UnitWeight As Double
    Public TotalWeight As Double
    Public UnitCost As Double
    Public TotalCost As Double
End Structure
```

I declare the list as a module level variable just inside the class declaration:

```
Public CustomerItemsList As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection
```

The listener for the click event just grabs the info and adds it to the new CustomerItem and adds it to the collection (which fails I think).

```
Protected Sub btnAddItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddItem.Click
    Dim CustomerItem As CustomerProduct
    CustomerItem.Description = ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 0)
    CustomerItem.ItemQty = txtItemQty.Text
    CustomerItem.BulkFee = ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 1)
    CustomerItem.UnitWeight = ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 2)
    CustomerItem.TotalWeight = Double.Parse(ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 2)) * Double.Parse(txtItemQty.Text)
    CustomerItem.UnitCost = ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 3)
    CustomerItem.TotalCost = CustomerItem.UnitCost * CustomerItem.ItemQty

    CustomerItemsList.Add(CustomerItem)
End Sub
```

I check to see if it's added by checking the count on reload-

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Response.Write("<br>Page has been posted back.")
        Response.Write(CustomerItemsList.Count) 'shows up 0 currently.
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: is the collection being initialized twice? it should only be created when the page is not posting back

Comment: It is on the module level, so perhaps move it down to the Else block to declare it?

Comment: Seems that if I initialize it anywhere else, the postback page shows it as null reference.

Comment: you will need to store the collection in session http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287643/asp-net-with-c-sharp-keeping-a-list-on-postback

Comment: Thank you @EdmundYeung99

Comment: Why is that type a structure? Unless you have a good reason for that, make it a class because it is bigger than a structure should generally be.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I the reasoning is that this is a project for a vb course, and the professor would like students to demonstrate the use of a struct in this particular project. Generally I would have used a class.